# EoF error for CRLF within quotes (common-csv)

Tags: java, apache-commons-csv

I'm getting following error while reading csv from hdfs-
`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: (startline 1) EOF reached before encapsulated token finished`
when i looked into csv file found CRLF (newline) within column is causing this.
How to tackle this?

I'm using commons-csv-1.4

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `dos2unix` command, or change lines with something like

`String withoutCRLF = withCRLF.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n");`

Comment: Yes this could have been the solution, but my buffer reader's `br.readLine();` is breaking content after encountering CRLF

Comment: Are you using BufferedReader (FileReader) to read content of file?
What system are you using? I'm using Scientific Linux (RHEL) 7.2 with Java 1.8 and I'm able to read file with BufferedReader no matter is it's CRLF (unix2dos) or normal (dos2unix).

Comment: There [code](http://pastebin.com/fAtT9j4H) is code that I used in both cases working like charm.